# Adding column to table in Latex and optimizing columns width

Tags: tables

Here is my table:
[image: table]

This is my code for it:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3} 
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, makecell} %
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
        \centering
        \sisetup{table-format=1.3, table-number-alignment=center, tight-spacing,}% table-column-width =2.5cm 
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
        \small
        \centering

        \sisetup{detect-weight,mode=text}
        \renewrobustcmd{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
        \renewrobustcmd{\boldmath}{}
        % abbreviation
        \newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}
        % shorten the intercolumn spaces
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l>{\centering}XSSS}
        \toprule

        \thead {DDDDDD \\ NNNNN}  & {\thead{No. of PPPPPP \\ rrrrr} }& {\thead{Delta CCCCC\\ AAAA }} & {\thead{EEEEEEEEEE\\ ccc} }
        & {\thead{PPPPPP Alg\\ccc} } \\ [0.5ex]
        \midrule
        POOO HHHH & AAAA to BBBB & 0.524 & 0.546 & \B 0.547  \\
        POOO HHHH & CCCC to DDDD & 0.554 & \B 0.546 & \B 0.546  \\
        POOO HHHH& AAAA to BBBB & 0.988 & \B0.831    & \B 0.831  \\
        POOO HHHH& CCCC to DDDD & 0.780 & \B0.784   & \B 0.754 \\ 
        CCCCCCC  & AAAA to BBBB & 0.622 & 0.723 & \B 0.735
         \\ 
        CCCCCCC & CCCC to DDDD & 0.563 &  \B0.674 & 0.665
         \\ 
        AAAAAA  & AAAA to BBBB & 0.956 & \B 0.957 & 0.956 \\
        AAAAAA  & CCCC to DDDD & 0.949 & \B0.955 & \B 0.955 \\
        JJJJJ  & RRRRR       & 0.999 & \B 1.000 & 0.999 \\
        JJJJJ  & KKKKKK    & 0.998 & \B 0.999 & 0.998\\
        JJJJJ  & HSDFFDSSDF & 0.627 & 0.638 & \B 0.646 \\
        JJJJJ  & HSDFFDSSDF & 0.647 & 0.653 & \B 0.654 \\   [1ex]
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    %    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Comparison between aaaaa to bbbbb (In \textbf{Bold} the most accurate per line)}
    \label{table:2}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I would like to add at the `end of the table` another column, with numbers. In addition, I would like to optimize the columns width so that the second column won't be so wide. How can I do it?

Comment: please, extend your code snippet to complete small document with your table. information contained in your document preamble are important for helping you. added one more column: just write it where you like to ad (`& ...`)

Comment: in your mwe are still missing some packages ... where you like to ad  new column? after last in temporary table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a `tabularx` and only having one `X` column, which is allowed to stretch, this column is forced to be very wide. If it should have its natural width, use a normal `tabular` instead.

For adding an additional column with numbers, add one `S` column and add them at the end of each line with `& <number>`

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3} 
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, makecell} %
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
        \centering
        \sisetup{table-format=1.3, table-number-alignment=center, tight-spacing,}% table-column-width =2.5cm 
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
        \small
        \centering

        \sisetup{detect-weight,mode=text}
        \renewrobustcmd{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
        \renewrobustcmd{\boldmath}{}
        % abbreviation
        \newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}
        % shorten the intercolumn spaces
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
        \begin{tabular}{l>{\centering}lSSSS}
        \toprule

        \thead {DDDDDD \\ NNNNN}  & {\thead{No. of PPPPPP \\ rrrrr} }& {\thead{Delta CCCCC\\ AAAA }} & {\thead{EEEEEEEEEE\\ ccc} }
        & {\thead{PPPPPP Alg\\ccc} } & {\thead{foo}} \\ [0.5ex]
        \midrule
        POOO HHHH & AAAA to BBBB & 0.524 & 0.546 & \B 0.547 & 0.780 \\
        POOO HHHH & CCCC to DDDD & 0.554 & \B 0.546 & \B 0.546  & 0.780\\
        POOO HHHH& AAAA to BBBB & 0.988 & \B0.831    & \B 0.831 & 0.780 \\
        POOO HHHH& CCCC to DDDD & 0.780 & \B0.784   & \B 0.754& 0.780 \\ 
        CCCCCCC  & AAAA to BBBB & 0.622 & 0.723 & \B 0.735
        & 0.780 \\ 
        CCCCCCC & CCCC to DDDD & 0.563 &  \B0.674 & 0.665
        & 0.780 \\ 
        AAAAAA  & AAAA to BBBB & 0.956 & \B 0.957 & 0.956 & 0.780\\
        AAAAAA  & CCCC to DDDD & 0.949 & \B0.955 & \B 0.955 & 0.780\\
        JJJJJ  & RRRRR       & 0.999 & \B 1.000 & 0.999 & 0.780\\
        JJJJJ  & KKKKKK    & 0.998 & \B 0.999 & 0.998& 0.780\\
        JJJJJ  & HSDFFDSSDF & 0.627 & 0.638 & \B 0.646 & 0.780\\
        JJJJJ  & HSDFFDSSDF & 0.647 & 0.653 & \B 0.654& 0.780 \\   [1ex]
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    %    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Comparison between aaaaa to bbbbb (In \textbf{Bold} the most accurate per line)}
    \label{table:2}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
    \newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{#1}}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \renewrobustcmd{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
    \newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-format=1.3,
             detect-weight,
             mode=text}
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll SS SS}
    \toprule
\mcx{DDDDDD\newline NNNNN}
    &   \mcx{No. of PPPPPP \newline rrrrr}
        &   \mcx{Delta CCCCC\newline AAAA }
            &   \mcx{EEEEEEEEEE\newline ccc}
                &   \mcx{PPPPPP Alg\newline ccc}
                    &   \mcx{here is\newline new column}
                        \\
    \midrule
POOO HHHH   & AAAA to BBBB & 0.524 &    0.546   & \B 0.547  & 1.234 \\
POOO HHHH   & CCCC to DDDD & 0.554 & \B 0.546   & \B 0.546  & 5.678 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
%    \end{tabular}
\caption{Comparison between aaaaa to bbbbb (In \textbf{Bold} the most accurate per line)}
\label{table:2}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

above *mwe* provide equal widths of columns. since real content c cells and cells heads are unknown, this might not be the best choice. let me know. beside this, i move `\newcommand`s to document preamble and remove superfluous `\sisetup` and preserve `tabularx` table environment.